# Pájina, jénero, zoolojía: ¿Grafías antiguas?

Tags: historia, ortografía, chile

En el periódico chileno "El Mercurio", con fecha 28 de mayo de 1908, aparece [en portada](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a8/El_Mercurio_-_28_de_mayo_de_1908.jpg), ([Edición completa en PDF](http://www.memoriachilena.gob.cl/archivos2/pdfs/MC0012297.pdf)):

> EDICION DE 12 **PAJINAS**

Inmediatamente asumí que era un error ortográfico, sin embargo, en la página 3, hay un anuncio sobre otra publicación (énfasis mio):

> **PÁJINAS** CHILENAS - Al precio de $ 2.50 [...] Tiene 600 **pájinas** y contiene hermosas ilustraciones.

Leyendo otros anuncios también encontramos una publicidad de La Gran Sastrería Económica que reza:

> [...] en igualdad de **jéneros** y forros.

En la página 9 encontramos:

> Clase de **zoolojía**

¿Qué ocurre aquí? ¿Se escribían así estas palabras a principios del siglo XX? Otras fuentes incluso anteriores parecen indicar lo contrario.

Answer (score 4):

En Chile se adoptó oficialmente en 1844 una reforma ortográfica conocida como [Ortografía de Bello](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ortograf%C3%ADa_de_Bello), también conocida como ortografía chilena.

La ortografía reformada se utilizó oficialmente hasta 1927, cuando fue reemplazada por las reglas ortográficas de la Real Academia Española.

La reforma buscaba lograr la correspondencia perfecta entre grafemas y fonemas. Entre otos cambios, la ortografía de Bello consistía en sustituir por «j» el sonido fricativo sordo de la «g» (jeneral, jinebra) y la «x» (Méjico, Jiménez).

[image: escuela de ingeniería, con j]